# Scrapy spider not found error

Tags: python, scrapy

This is Windows 7 with python 2.7

I have a scrapy project in a directory called caps (this is where scrapy.cfg is)

My spider is located in caps\caps\spiders\campSpider.py

I cd into the scrapy project  and try to run

```
scrapy crawl campSpider -o items.json -t json
```

I get an error that the spider can't be found. The class name *is* `campSpider`

```
...
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7-win32.egg\scrapy\spidermanager.py", l
ine 43, in create
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
KeyError: 'Spider not found: campSpider'
```

Am I missing some configuration item?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Make sure you have set the **"name" property** of the spider. 
Example:

```
class campSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = 'campSpider'
```

Without the name property, the scrapy manager will not be able to find your spider.

Comment: according to [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), the name can be used without `Spider`. But the class name should!

Answer (score 29):

Also make sure that your project is not called `scrapy`! I made that mistake and renaming it fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad i saw this before spending hours trying to figure it out :P

Comment: Make sure your python file is not named `scrapy.py` either.

Answer (score 9):

Try running `scrapy list` on the command line. If there is any error on the spider it will detect it.

In my case, I was bluntly copy code from another project and forget to change the project name from the spider module import

Comment: This solved my problem, should be at the top.

Answer (score 8):

Have you set up the [SPIDER_MODULES](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#spider-modules) setting?

> `SPIDER_MODULES`
>
> Default: `[]`
>
> A list of modules where Scrapy will look for spiders.
>
> Example:
>
> `SPIDER_MODULES = ['mybot.spiders_prod', 'mybot.spiders_dev']`

Answer (score 4):

You have to give a name to your spider.

However, **BaseSpider** is *deprecated*, use **Spider** instead.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
class campSpider(Spider):
   name = 'campSpider'
```

The project should have been created by the startproject command:

```
scrapy startproject project_name
```

Which gives you the following directory tree:

```
project_name/
    scrapy.cfg            # deploy configuration file

    project_name/             # project's Python module, you'll import your code from here
        __init__.py

        items.py          # project items file

        pipelines.py      # project pipelines file

        settings.py       # project settings file

        spiders/          # a directory where you'll later put your spiders
            __init__.py
            ...
```

Make sure that ***settings.py*** has the definition of your spider module.
eg:

```
BOT_NAME = 'bot_name' # Usually equals to your project_name 

SPIDER_MODULES = ['project_name.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'project_name.spiders'
```

You should have no problems to run your spider locally or on [ScrappingHub](http://scrapinghub.com/).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might have the same problem, not only you need to set the `name` of the spider and check for  `SPIDER_MODULES` and `NEWSPIDER_MODULE` in your scrapy settings, if you are running a `scrapyd` service, you also need to restart in order to apply any change you have made

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your spider file is saved in your spider directory. the Crawler looks for the spider name in the spider directory

Answer (score 1):

**Name** attribute in CrawlSpider class defines the spider name and this name is used in command line for calling the spider to work.

```
import json

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor

class NameSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'name of spider'
    allowed_domains = ['allowed domains of web portal to be scrapped']
    start_urls = ['start url of of web portal to be scrapped']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    }

    product_css = ['.main-menu']
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=product_css), callback='parse'),
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        //implementation of business logic
```

Answer (score 1):

without project use runspider and fileName
with project use crawl and name
sample : `C/user> scrapy runspider myFile.py`

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem,and it turned out to be rather small. Be sure your class inherits from `scrapy.Spider`

```
my_class(scrapy.Spider):
```

Answer (score 1):

just to add my learning point here.

I had my crawler working, it suddenly started giving the error and came here to find the solution.

couldn't fix it, so checked my changes and i stupidly created a new variable "name".

This causes scrapy to not find the spider name also.

Comment: I defined a static method named "name"... Same effect. Thanks, if it wasn't for you, I would be wondering what's wrong with my spider for the next 10 hours or so

Answer (score 0):

Check indentation too, the class for my spider was indented one tab. Somehow that makes the class invalid or something.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i set 'LOG_STDOUT=True', and scrapyd can not return the results to json response when you are looking for your spiders with '/listspiders.json'. And instead of that, the results are being printed to the log files you set at scrapyd's default_scrapyd.conf file. 
So, I changed the settings as this, and it worked well.

```
LOG_STDOUT = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh Yes, you should enter the value of your 'name variable value'.

I.e.

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titleText' : title}
```

So in this case, the name = 'quotes'.
Then in your command line you enter:
'scrapy crawl quotes'

That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the tutorial from https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Then do something like:

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
$ pip install Scrapy
(logout, login)
$ cd
$ scrapy startproject tutorial
$ vi ~/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/quotes_spider.py
$ cd ~/tutorial/tutorial
$ scrapy crawl quotes
```

The error happens if you try to create the spiders directory yourself under `~/tutorial`

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is possible that you have not deployed your spider. SO first use "scrapyd" to up the server and then use "scrapyd-deploy" to deploy and then run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this strange behaviour is caused by `LOG_STDOUT = True`

It defaults to `False` though, so check it and if it is set to `True` - try to set it to default

`LOG_STDOUT = False`

This is a [logged issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client/issues/43)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When i was using "scrapy list" in cmd the command listed the spider name i was getting the error for, in the list, but while i tried to run it with scrapy crawl SpiderName.py, i used to get Scrapy spider not found error. 
I have used this spider before and everything was fine with it.
So i used the secret weapon, i restarted my system and the issue was resolved :D

Answer (score 0):

Ensure same name attribute is used in the command line for running spider ...

scrapy crawl

Comment: This is an old question with well defined and accepted answer. Your answer lacks more detail. Don't get me wrong, I got your post from a review queue. I try to help you understand how this site works. Long story short, this answer doesn't add much to the discussion and you might consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by fixing my filename.

Originally, `my.spider.py`. Fixed, `myspider.py`.

I'm very new to python and scrapy so I'm not sure if this is a dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

An improper name for the python file could lead to this error (for example `crawler.py` or `scrapy.py`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem like this by running the spider from the directory but just from where the "spider.cfg" file is located, NOT the complete route, in which in your case  the campSpider.py is located (caps\caps\spiders\campSpider.py).

Well, try only from caps\

Also from this place I suggest running the command: scrapy list

this would show you the spiders you have created.

I hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the file extension for the spider file can also lead to this error. If instead of `my-project/spiders/my-spider.py` you name your file `my-project/spiders/my-spider` you will get exactly this error.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners that still could not find a solution to the issue,note that you must initiate the spider using the spider name,that means if you set the spider filename to be spider1.py and within the file you set

```
name = 'basic'
```

then you must type

```
scrapy crawl basic
```

to initiate the spider

and not

```
scrapy crawl spider1
```