# KeyError: 'Spider not found: spider'

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project called crawler.

my spider looks like this:

```
class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wiki-spider"

    def start_requests(self):    
        for url in CrawlerUrls().wiki:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # first part: save pages html to bigdata directory
        page = response.url.split("/")[4]
        page_dirname = 'bigdata'
        filename = '%s.html' % page
        with open(os.path.join(page_dirname,filename), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename) 

        # second part: extract text for the item for document corpus
        item = CrawlerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        item['text'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//text()')\
                           .extract()                                                             
        tags_list = [response.url.split("/")[2],
                     response.url.split("/")[3]]
        more_tags = [x.lower() for x in remove_stopwords(response.url\
                            .split("/")[4].split("_"))]
        for tag in more_tags:
            tag = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', tag)  # alphanumeric values only  
            tags_list.append(tag)
        item['tags'] = tags_list                 
        return item
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
  File "c:\users\oerha\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: spider'
```

I looked at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876793/scrapy-spider-not-found-error), it looks like I'm doing everything right.

this is my setting:

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders'
```

run-spider.py

```
import scrapy  # object-oriented framework for crawling and scraping
import os  # operating system commands

page_dirnames = ['wiki']

for name in page_dirnames:
  if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.makedirs(name)

# function for walking and printing directory structure
def list_all(current_directory):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_directory):
    level = root.replace(current_directory, '').count(os.sep)
    indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
    print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
    subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
    for f in files:
      print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))

# examine the directory structure
current_directory = os.getcwd()
list_all(current_directory)

# list the avaliable spiders
print('\nScrapy spider names:\n')
os.system('scrapy list')

# for JSON lines we use this command
os.system('scrapy crawl spider -o items.jl')
print('\nJSON lines written to items.jl\n')

# run the scraper exporting results as a dictionary XML text file items.xml
# os.system('scrapy crawl quotes -o items.xml')
```

I run the file using python run-spider.py

Comment: Why is it looking for a name of `spider` when you defined your name to be `wiki-spider`?  Can you show us how you run this program?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm not sure why it is looking for that,  I have updated the question with the way I run it

Comment: Perhaps it's because your scrapy command is `scrapy crawl spider -o items.jl`?

Comment: yup that was the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run using run-spider.py instead of spider

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31322625)