# Issue running in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have started to learn scrapy but I am facing issue running my first spider in VSCode

```
import scrapy
class QuotesScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title').extract()
        yield{'title_text':title}
```

when I run "scrapy crawl quotes" in terminal, it gives below error

```
KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: The code is correct.
Here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876793/scrapy-spider-not-found-error) you find various ideas to prevent this error.

Comment: Can you share an image of your folder structure? And also, where do you run the command?

Comment: I just closed VSCODE , ran the command again and it worked. It happens sometimes with libraries too. Thanks guys.  One more ques, after I run the spider, lot of stuff is printed on terminal like downloader.., logs etc., making hard to find output. I just need output tag or error if any. is that possible?

Comment: @Samir check [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html) out. set the log level to the desired level, or if you don't any log messages just set 'LOG_ENABLED=False'